# Bouncing effect using css3 keyframes animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying bouncing effect using [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) key-frame animation.
here is fiddle link: [`click`](https://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/v7nk207y/)

Background of box is changing but my requirement is to give bouncing effect to background image not background color.

**What exactly I need**: A bouncing(jumping) teddy on trampoline with two states:
(1. with arms up, 2. with arms down) while jumping.

Any ideas how to achieve it? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something for that?

Comment: Yes I got solution just now. 
I used two images and change z-index in keyframe animation

Comment: ok. If still any issue then show use your code. we will try to solve it.

Comment: @Sharanpreet, you can post your answer to ur own Question; it will help future viewers

Answer (score 3):

I got solution for this:

```css
.margin{
    margin-top:200px;
}
} 
/* keyframes definition for WebKit browsers */

@-webkit-keyframes travel {
  from { right: 10px;     }
  to   { right: 10px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from, to  {
    bottom: 40px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 140px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce1 {
  from, to  {
    bottom: 40px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 140px;
 z-index:9;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}


/* keyframes definition for other browsers */

@keyframes travel {
  from { right: 10px;     }
  to   { right:  10px;   }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from, to  {
    bottom: 45px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 140px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 
  }
}
@keyframes bounce1 {
  from, to  {
    bottom: 45px;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 140px;
 z-index:9;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 
  }
}

/* styles for the stage and animated elements */

#traveler {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation-name: travel;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-duration:2.8s;

  animation-name: travel;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 2.8s;
}

#bouncer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  z-index:10;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*background: url(../img/jump.png) no-repeat;*/
    background:green;
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;

  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
}
#bouncer2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:11;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*background: url(../img/pyonpyon.png) no-repeat;*/
    background:red;
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;

  animation-name: bounce1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
<div id="traveler">
           <div id="bouncer"> </div>
     <div id="bouncer2"> </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/eyjkpy8u/

Thank you

Comment: okay, but u asked for : 1. with arms up, 2. with arms down while jumping! idea dropped?

Comment: it gives same jumping effect. I have two images 1 with teddy arms down and 2nd with arms up. and both images bounce simultaneously. the only difference is z-index. I used  z-index property to shuffle images .

Comment: okay, so its' working now! what mentioned in answer is not that relevant to it. Actually effect in [Question](https://jsfiddle.net/Sharan_thethy/v7nk207y/) is better than ans.! :)